# How is a sufficient complete estimator minimal sufficient

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

the question is quite theoretical

But I am finding it extremely hard to understand it without cramming the derivation ,although I understand the basic concept of it .

Can someone explain how a sufficient complete statistic , minimal sufficient?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/435938/119261

Comment: @stubbornatom , in which subject are you doing masters in Statistics?